# Format Table Style in PowerPoint from Excel - 2013

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I have the following code block that loops through an array of table names in a workbook. It is a ParamArray from a calling procedure (Callback). It copies each table and pastes it to the ppt slide. Then it creates a textbox, which is the title for the table. I am pasting it using the destination style (which I think is the default) because I want to use ppt styles. The object I am pasting from Excel is a table. How can I change the style of the table after it is pasted and make the first row bold? Changing PowerPoint Table Styles doesn't seem to be well documented. I tried the commented section below but it didn't work. Thank you!

```
For i = LBound(vObjects(0)) To UBound(vObjects(0))
        Set practice = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Range("T_" & vObjects(0)(i)).Parent.Name).ListObjects("T_" & vObjects(0)(i))
        practice.Range.Copy
        PPT_Slide.Shapes.Paste 'Special DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoTrue
        Set PPT_Shape = PPT_Slide.Shapes(PPT_Slide.Shapes.Count)
        PPT_Shape.Name = "OBJ_" & vObjects(0)(i)
'        With PPT_Shape
'            .ApplyStyle "{C083E6E3-FA7D-4D7B-A595-EF9225AFEA82}", True
'            .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
'        End With
        Set objPPT_MilestoneTextbox = PPT_Slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, Left:=320, Top:=HorizontalTop, Width:=300, Height:=50).TextFrame.TextRange
        With objPPT_MilestoneTextbox
            .Text = vObjects(0)(i)
            .Font.Size = 14
            .Font.Bold = True
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2
        End With
        Set PPT_Shape = PPT_Slide.Shapes(PPT_Slide.Shapes.Count)
        PPT_Shape.Name = "CAP_" & vObjects(0)(i)
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This MS page documents the table style ids for PPT 2010 (and points out that they may not be the same for subsequent versions):

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/PowerPoint-2010-Interact-ea2fbe1b

But you need to apply the style to the shape's .Table object, not to the shape itself.  Try modifying your code like this:

```
Dim otbl As Table
Set PPT_Shape = PPT_Slide.Shapes(PPT_Slide.Shapes.Count)
Set otbl = PPT_Shape.Table
With otbl
    .ApplyStyle "{C083E6E3-FA7D-4D7B-A595-EF9225AFEA82}", True
End With
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Steve.